# Flexbox sticky footer in safari on mobile device

Tags: html, css, flexbox, mobile-safari

I've used flexbox to stick a form to the bottom of a page. The submit button is supposed to be the footer of the page. This does work in Chrome and Safari, however in mobile Safari, when the textarea is in focus and the keyboard pops out, there is a white space under the button and you can scroll a little bit down.

1. [Normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5qio.png)
2. [When textarea is focused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9yRv.png)

How can I prevent this? This is the code I'm using

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.Site {
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main {
  flex: 1;
}

.text-wrapper {
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.text {
  resize: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: red;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-style: none;
  border-width: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="Site">
      <div class="main">

      </div>
      <div>
        <form class="footer-form" action="index.html" method="post">
          <div class="text-wrapper">
            <textarea class="text"></textarea>
          </div>
          <input class="footer" type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looking into it, you're seeing white because `body` has no CSS colour added to it within the styling.

Comment: That's right but ideally the button should stick to the bottom of the page so there wouldn't be a gap where the body is visible.